# loop through and compare 2 array lists and find a match

Tags: java, arraylist, removeall

I have 2 array lists.  I want to return the unique value between the two.  How is this done?

```
String[] s1 = {10, 1};
String[] s2 = {10, 1, 13};

//loop through and compare element of s1 to s2     
//switch varialbe used to indicate whether a match was found
boolean matchFound = false;

//outer loop for all the elements in s2
for (int i = 0; i < s2.lenght; i++) {
  //inner loop for all the elements in s1
  for (int i = 0; i < s1.lenght; i++) {
     matchFound = true;
     System.out.println("This " + s2[i] + "was found");
  }
}
if(matchFound == false) {
  System.out.println("This " + s2[i] + "was not found");
}
//set matchFound bool back to false
matchFound = false;
}
```

Comment: Literals like `10` and `1` are **not** `String` literals

Comment: Your code does not compile. If you change the integers to strings (`"10"` vs `10`) this works just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include the whole code.  These strings are passing from my servlet and I'm passing it to the DAO.  I update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my question with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your array don't have the duplicate values or you are interested only in the elements not in the occurance, then you can use Set.

Convert the arrays to two sets:

> `Set<T> one = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(s1));`
>
> `Set<T> two = = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(s2));`
>
> `one.removeAll(secondSet);`
>
> `two.removeAll(firstSet);`

if both sets are empty then both sets were equal, otherwise each set have the unique element.